# How can I debug Azure function using Visual Studio?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I'm trying to debug the Azure function, but it exists with the error "Unknown argument debug".

Please find below the screenshot of the project debug configuration.

[image: Visual Studio Screenshot]

I have referred to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local).

When I run without `--debug vs`, the application runs perfectly fine but I'm not able to hit the breakpoint.

I have tried host start --debug vs also, but it's also not working.

It gives the following exception.

[image: Exception]

Comment: I suppose it just does not work, tried the same :). I assume you targeting netstandard2.0 - in that case, you can use another app (console or web app) which will reference your Azure Function and debug it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue with the help of [this link](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/623). In my case, it was the cases when the Windows username contained spaces.

Change the *launchSettings.json* file to something like this:

```
"newProfile1": {
      "commandName": "Executable",
      "executablePath": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe",
      "commandLineArgs": "\"C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\azure-functions-core-tools\\bin\\Azure.Functions.Cli.dll\" host start",
      "workingDirectory": "$(TargetDir)"
    }
```

Comment: What is the gist of it? Escaping the user name somehow? Quoting? Changing the user name? Can you add it to the answer? (But ************ ***without*** ************ "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today

Answer (score 0):

```sh
$ func --debug vs host start

                  %%%%%%
                 %%%%%%
            @   %%%%%%    @
          @@   %%%%%%      @@
       @@@    %%%%%%%%%%%    @@@
     @@      %%%%%%%%%%        @@
       @@         %%%%       @@
         @@      %%%       @@
           @@    %%      @@
                %%
                %

Error: unknown argument --debug
```

Just place your options after the action (verb), you know à la BSD.

For example:

```sh
$ func host start --debug vs
```

This is mentioned in usage:

```sh
$ func

...
Usage: func [context] [context] <action> [-/--options]
```

Comment: I have modified my question for better understanding.